# xampp is not starting mysql after changing port number

Tags: mysql, xampp

9:44:05 AM  [mysql]     Problem detected!

9:44:05 AM  [mysql]     Port 3306 in use by "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\mysql-5.7.13-winx64\mysql-5.7.13-winx64\bin\mysqld mysql2"!

9:44:05 AM  [mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

9:44:05 AM  [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application

9:44:05 AM  [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

9:44:05 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL service...

after changing the port number in my.ini from 3306 to 3307 and the httpq.conf localhost from 80 to 442, mysql did not want to start up.
I read things online saying that using command "sc delete mysql" to delete the current mysql that is installed.

would "sc delete mysql" delete any of the data stored? 
It was working fine before we had a power outage it just stopped working.

after changing the port number in the control panel, i get this

10:09:36 AM  [mysql]    MySQL Service detected with wrong path

10:09:36 AM  [mysql]    Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or

10:09:36 AM  [mysql]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first

10:09:36 AM  [mysql]    Found Path: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld MySQL

10:09:36 AM  [mysql]    Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql

SOLUTION:
This is how i fixed this problem.
I deleted my old mysql using "sc delete mysql" and did not delete my stored data
then after that, I went into xampp and deleted the mysql from module service and reinstall it.
then I went into C:\xampp\mysql\data directory and deleted ibdata1 and all the ib_logfile changed the port from 3306 to 3307 on the xampp control panel and also in the ini.my file. Also edited the errors in ini.my file.
found all my backup file that was stored C:..\mysqldatabackup to the current place where my data is stored now. (well almost. some of the files were corrupted)
after that, it worked like a charm and all my data is restored.
I hope this will help someone from going through some trouble.

Comment: Did you try restarting the computer the server is running on?

Comment: yeah, i restarted the computer multiple times.

Comment: What happens if you go into the control panel in XAMPP and change the port there instead of manually changing the ini?

Comment: if i change it in the control panel, it gets stuck on "Attempting to start MySQL service..."

Comment: 10:02:35 AM  [mysql]  MySQL Service detected with wrong path

10:02:35 AM  [mysql]  Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or

10:02:35 AM  [mysql]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first

10:02:35 AM  [mysql]  Found Path: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld MySQL

10:02:35 AM  [mysql]  Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I've changed ports before in XAMPP using the control panel and never had an issue.

Comment: i just figured out the problem. i posted my solutions in the post itself. thanks for your help, carcigenicate.

Comment: Good to hear. Your should post it as an answer though. It's fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
This is how i fixed this problem.
I deleted my old mysql using "sc delete mysql" and did not delete my stored data
then after that, I went into xampp and deleted the mysql from module service and reinstall it.
then I went into C:\xampp\mysql\data directory and deleted ibdata1 and all the ib_logfile changed the port from 3306 to 3307 on the xampp control panel and also in the ini.my file. Also edited the errors in ini.my file.
found all my backup file that was stored C:..\mysqldatabackup to the current place where my data is stored now. (well almost. some of the files were corrupted)
after that, it worked like a charm and all my data is restored.
I hope this will help someone from going through some trouble.